# Remove Vertical-Align in INPUT TAG with JQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

my problem is very strange: i've this input control in my aspx page

```
<div style="vertical-align: top;margin-top:10px; width: 100%;">
<div id="boxMatr" class="form-field" style="width: 100%;">`
<label for="txtMatr" class="lblForm">Matr</label>
<input class="typeahead" id="txtMatr" type="text" placeholder="[Matr]" />
</div>
</div>
```

i've associated a tips box with bootstrap3 (twitter typeahed).

The strange thing is that at first time the control appears with a little space on top because has added dynamically a tag

vertical-align: top;

if i reload the page (clicking on the same link on the form) controls appears correctly with space on top.

This is HTML code produced on browser

```
        <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; direction: ltr;">
        <input class="typeahead tt-hint" type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
        <input class="typeahead tt-input" id="txtMatr" type="text" placeholder="[Matr]" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" dir="auto">
```

And this is a piece of code in file .js that initialize controls

```
$('#boxMatr .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1,
  matcher: function(item) {
    if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
      return true;
    }
  },
  sorter: function(items) {
    return items.sort();
  }
}, {
  displayKey: 'id',
  source: matr.ttAdapter()
});
```

i don't understand where/when that tag

vertical-align: top;

has added to control. I presume some inheritance but i can't able to resolve.

A solution may be ovverride style for that control but i don't know where put code and what code.

Thanks in advance for any type of help.

Answer (score 0):

Once initialized, you can perform:

```
$("#txtMatr").css("vertical-align", "inherit");
```

This should change the the `style` attribute seen here:

```
<input class="typeahead tt-input" id="txtMatr" type="text" placeholder="[Matr]" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" dir="auto">
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No changes has been produced.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is apply the same vertical-align of the label (or the same property of the others control) in .js file adding .css to the control with receive association with typeahead engine

```
$('#boxMatr .typeahead').typeahead(
{
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    matcher: function (item) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    sorter: function (items) {
        return items.sort();
    }
},
{
    displayKey: 'id',
    source: matr.ttAdapter()
})
    **.css('vertical-align', 'middle');// label position**


}
```

Thanks for support.